# Merge Rows in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I have some lines (rows) in excel in the following form : 
[image]

I need to transform it to the following form : [image]

I'm not a good user of MS Excel and I am using the french version.

Thanks

Comment: Are values always from name of the days? (Monday to Sunday)

Comment: No, difeerent types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MergeRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim c, key

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    ' Change this to where your source data is
    With Sheet17
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 10), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row, 10))
    End With

    For Each c In rng
        If Not dict.exists(c.Value2) Then
            ReDim tmp(1 To 3)
            dict.Add key:=c.Value2, Item:=tmp
        End If
        j = 1
        tmp = dict(c.Value2)
        Do
            If Not c.Offset(0, j).Value2 = vbNullString Then tmp(j) = c.Offset(0, j).Value2
            j = j + 1
        Loop Until j > UBound(tmp)
        dict(c.Value2) = tmp
    Next c
    ' Change this to where you want your output
    With Sheet17.Range("A2")
        i = 0
        For Each key In dict.keys
            .Offset(i, 0).Value2 = key
            .Offset(i, 1).Resize(, UBound(dict(key))) = dict(key)
            i = i + 1
        Next key
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Fun problem, here's my take using formulae but there's sure to be solutions out there that are better.

It uses three helper columns to the right of your options' columns:

1-Identify which option is chosen by finding the (first) non-blank cell in the row (as per [these](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-first-non-blank-value-in-a-list) instructions). Put the first range as your header row (option1, option2, ... optionn) and the second range as your row from option1 through optionn. It should look something like this: `=INDEX($K$1:$M$1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(K2:M2),0))` and note that it should be an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter)

2-Use a simple index+match to register the choice. Assuming the first helper column is in column N, this is: `=INDEX(k2:m2,MATCH(n2,$k$1:$m$1,0))`

3-Concatenate the address and option name to make it possible to look up the address-option combination. This is simply: `=J2&N2`

Once this is done, you create a simple table with only single Addresses in the left most column and Options as a header row (depending on the number of addresses, you might want to use a pivot table to populate them). Then you have an index-match to find your results: 
`=INDEX($O$2:$O$6,MATCH($J9&K$8,$P$2:$P$6,0))`.

[image]

And you should be done.